# Seeking Advice for Exam FM regarding Derivatives Markets

Tags: finance

I am taking Exam FM in a week and I was wondering if I could get any advice from people who have recently passed this exam.

How much of the derivatives markets question did show up?  I am using the online sample exam from SOA candidate support, would that be a pretty accurate source?

Comment: I think you may be asking this question on wrong site. Quants are quite different in actuaries. Most don't take actuary exams

Comment: But I did take it in February and derivatives showed up a decent amount. Lots of valuation and bond questions

Comment: Hello, Kamster.  I sat for the April exam and I failed.  I signed up for the June exam, but I feel as though there is not enough resource for me to really get good practice for the exam.  Would it be okay if I asked you what kind of materials you used?  I especially am not comfortable with derivatives markets and honestly, the book that the SOA posted as a useful resource has no problems that resembles that of the questions I saw on the test.

Comment: The best will be to go on https://www.coachingactuaries.com and buy the fm exam test package. This will have randomly genrated test that you can change difficulty in (actual test will be 4-7) and just do a bunch of those. My friend that ossed used this and said it really helped her

Comment: I also used the ASM manual

Comment: Wow, I did not think that I would get such a great answer right away.  Thank you.  I will try looking at the exams.

Are you studying for MFE already, by the way?

Comment: Not exactly. My senior project though is incorporating some of the material in it